# Problem with optimizing an lpath-dependent query

Tags: postgresql, optimization, query-optimization, ltree

Application I am working on has a feature called `folders`. Folders may contain other folders, are owned by users and can be shared to other users.

The feature has been implemented and was working fine up until recently, when a particular API endpoint started to underperform. This API endpoint returns all folders owned by a calling user. Additionally, for each folder, a list of users who has access to the folder is returned (owning user would be one of them).

The schema of a folders table looks like this:

```
id
title
parent_id
path (of ltree type)
```

A table that contains sharing bits looks like this, a folder_visibility table:

```
id
folder_id
profile_id
```

Access to folder by a given profile_id is determined by 2 rules:

1. a `(folder_id, profile_id)` record exists in folder_visibility table,
2. a folder is a descended of another folder, for which there a `(folder_id, profile_id)` record exists.

Alternatively, first and second rules can be expressed together like this: if folder was shared with a user, the user can see this folder, as well as all of its descendants.

Problem is that implementing rule 2 efficiently seems hard to me.

Example. Below is my thinking process, together with test data:

```
create table folders (id uuid, title text, path ltree);
create table folder_visibility (id uuid, profile_id uuid, folder_id uuid);
insert into folders (id, title, path) values ('9ca5ed28-83c3-45c3-98a1-31ebf0466e63', 'Folder 1', '9ca5ed28_83c3_45c3_98a1_31ebf0466e63');
insert into folders (id, title, path) values ('80ba97ae-b21b-49d7-aedb-3004cdee0c21', 'Folder 2', '9ca5ed28_83c3_45c3_98a1_31ebf0466e63.80ba97ae_b21b_49d7_aedb_3004cdee0c21');
insert into folders (id, title, path) values ('a7abb686-2a69-44d1-b2cd-60825478c4c8', 'Folder 3', '9ca5ed28_83c3_45c3_98a1_31ebf0466e63.80ba97ae_b21b_49d7_aedb_3004cdee0c21.a7abb686_2a69_44d1_b2cd_60825478c4c8');
insert into folder_visibility (id, profile_id, folder_id) values (gen_random_uuid(), 'e63533e4-eb10-48f6-ae69-ddf5f9242510', '80ba97ae-b21b-49d7-aedb-3004cdee0c21');
insert into folder_visibility (id, profile_id, folder_id) values (gen_random_uuid(), '7cbb5f24-61d0-430e-ab10-225554b0725b', '9ca5ed28-83c3-45c3-98a1-31ebf0466e63');
insert into profiles values ('7cbb5f24-61d0-430e-ab10-225554b0725b', 'owner@server.com');
insert into profiles values ('e63533e4-eb10-48f6-ae69-ddf5f9242510', 'user@server.com');
create index on folder_visibility (profile_id);
create index on folder_visibility (folder_id);
create index on folders (folder_id);
create index on folders (id);
create index on profiles (id);
```

1. I fetch all folders for a given profile, this is relatively easy:

   ```
   select f2.id folder_id,
          p.id profile_id,
          p.email
     from folders f1
     join folders f2 on f2.path <@ f1.path
     join folder_visibility fv1 on fv1.folder_id = f1.id
     join profiles p on p.id = fv1.profile_id
    where fv1.profile_id = '7cbb5f24-61d0-430e-ab10-225554b0725b';
                 folder_id               |              profile_id              |      email
   --------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------------
    9ca5ed28-83c3-45c3-98a1-31ebf0466e63 | 7cbb5f24-61d0-430e-ab10-225554b0725b | owner@server.com
    80ba97ae-b21b-49d7-aedb-3004cdee0c21 | 7cbb5f24-61d0-430e-ab10-225554b0725b | owner@server.com
    a7abb686-2a69-44d1-b2cd-60825478c4c8 | 7cbb5f24-61d0-430e-ab10-225554b0725b | owner@server.com
   (3 rows)
   ```
2. From here, I complete rule 1 from above like this:

   ```
   select f2.id folder_id,
          p.id profile_id,
          p.email
     from folders f1
     join folders f2 on f2.path <@ f1.path
     join folder_visibility fv1 on fv1.folder_id = f1.id
     join folder_visibility fv2 on (fv2.folder_id = f1.id or fv2.folder_id = f2.id)
     join profiles p on p.id = fv2.profile_id
    where fv1.profile_id = '7cbb5f24-61d0-430e-ab10-225554b0725b';
                 folder_id               |              profile_id              |      email
   --------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------------
    9ca5ed28-83c3-45c3-98a1-31ebf0466e63 | 7cbb5f24-61d0-430e-ab10-225554b0725b | owner@server.com
    80ba97ae-b21b-49d7-aedb-3004cdee0c21 | 7cbb5f24-61d0-430e-ab10-225554b0725b | owner@server.com
    a7abb686-2a69-44d1-b2cd-60825478c4c8 | 7cbb5f24-61d0-430e-ab10-225554b0725b | owner@server.com
    80ba97ae-b21b-49d7-aedb-3004cdee0c21 | e63533e4-eb10-48f6-ae69-ddf5f9242510 | user@server.com
   (4 rows)
   ```
3. To implement rule 2, I'm naively adding yet another set of joins and finally get a list of necessary rows:

   ```
   select distinct on (f3.id, p.email)
          f3.id folder_id,
          p.email,
          fv3.profile_id
     from folders f1
     join folders f2 on f2.path operator(public.<@) f1.path
     join folder_visibility fv1 on fv1.folder_id = f1.id
     join folder_visibility fv2 on (fv2.folder_id = f1.id or fv2.folder_id = f2.id)
     join folders f3 on f3.path operator(public.<@) f2.path
     join folder_visibility fv3 on (fv3.folder_id = f2.id or fv3.folder_id = f3.id)
     join profiles p on p.id = fv3.profile_id
    where fv1.profile_id = '7cbb5f24-61d0-430e-ab10-225554b0725b';
                 folder_id               |      email       |              profile_id
   --------------------------------------+------------------+--------------------------------------
    80ba97ae-b21b-49d7-aedb-3004cdee0c21 | owner@server.com | 7cbb5f24-61d0-430e-ab10-225554b0725b
    80ba97ae-b21b-49d7-aedb-3004cdee0c21 | user@server.com  | e63533e4-eb10-48f6-ae69-ddf5f9242510
    9ca5ed28-83c3-45c3-98a1-31ebf0466e63 | owner@server.com | 7cbb5f24-61d0-430e-ab10-225554b0725b
    a7abb686-2a69-44d1-b2cd-60825478c4c8 | owner@server.com | 7cbb5f24-61d0-430e-ab10-225554b0725b
    a7abb686-2a69-44d1-b2cd-60825478c4c8 | user@server.com  | e63533e4-eb10-48f6-ae69-ddf5f9242510
   (5 rows)
   ```

Problem with the last step in my example is that the execution plan gets quite enormous:

```
                                                                           QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Unique  (cost=7.38..7.39 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=0.103..0.111 rows=5 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=7.38..7.39 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=0.103..0.106 rows=8 loops=1)
         Sort Key: f3.id, p.email
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..7.37 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=0.031..0.087 rows=8 loops=1)
               Join Filter: (fv3.profile_id = p.id)
               Rows Removed by Join Filter: 8
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..6.33 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.028..0.066 rows=8 loops=1)
                     Join Filter: ((fv3.folder_id = f2.id) OR (fv3.folder_id = f3.id))
                     Rows Removed by Join Filter: 8
                     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..5.28 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.025..0.046 rows=8 loops=1)
                           Join Filter: (f3.path OPERATOR(public.<@) f2.path)
                           Rows Removed by Join Filter: 4
                           ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..4.21 rows=1 width=48) (actual time=0.022..0.032 rows=4 loops=1)
                                 Join Filter: ((fv2.folder_id = f1.id) OR (fv2.folder_id = f2.id))
                                 Rows Removed by Join Filter: 2
                                 ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..3.16 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=0.018..0.022 rows=3 loops=1)
                                       Join Filter: (f2.path OPERATOR(public.<@) f1.path)
                                       ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..2.09 rows=1 width=48) (actual time=0.014..0.016 rows=1 loops=1)
                                             Join Filter: (f1.id = fv1.folder_id)
                                             Rows Removed by Join Filter: 2
                                             ->  Seq Scan on folder_visibility fv1  (cost=0.00..1.02 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.009..0.010 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                   Filter: (profile_id = '7cbb5f24-61d0-430e-ab10-225554b0725b'::uuid)
                                                   Rows Removed by Filter: 1
                                             ->  Seq Scan on folders f1  (cost=0.00..1.03 rows=3 width=48) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=3 loops=1)
                                       ->  Seq Scan on folders f2  (cost=0.00..1.03 rows=3 width=48) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=3 loops=1)
                                 ->  Seq Scan on folder_visibility fv2  (cost=0.00..1.02 rows=2 width=16) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=2 loops=3)
                           ->  Seq Scan on folders f3  (cost=0.00..1.03 rows=3 width=48) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=3 loops=4)
                     ->  Seq Scan on folder_visibility fv3  (cost=0.00..1.02 rows=2 width=32) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=2 loops=8)
               ->  Seq Scan on profiles p  (cost=0.00..1.02 rows=2 width=48) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=2 loops=8)
 Planning Time: 0.588 ms
 Execution Time: 0.151 ms
(32 rows)
```

On large data set (thousands of folders for a given profile) this query gets executed several seconds. What would be a more efficient way to grab all folders, together with all "visibilities" for each folder according to the two rules above?